# Use JavaScript to replace all characters in string with "p" except "o"

Tags: javascript, regex, replaceall, except

I would like to replace all characters in a string `myString` with "p", except "o".

For example:

```
"fgyerfgehooefwfweeo"
```

should become

```
"pppppppppoopppppppo"
```

I tried:

```
myString.replaceAll('[^o]*/g', 'p')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Pass a regular expression literal instead of a string to `replace` (or `replaceAll`).
- Do not use `*` after the character class; otherwise, multiple consecutive characters that are not "o" will be collapsed into a single "p".

```js
let str = "fgyerfgehooefwfweeo";
let res = str.replace(/[^o]/g, 'p');
console.log(res);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if anything more than a comment is warranted for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way without using `Regex`:
which [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string into `chars` and do [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with condition on letter 'o' then finally [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) them back.

```js
console.log("fgyerfgehooefwfweeo".split('').map(chr => chr !== 'o' ? 'p' : chr).join(''))
```

Comment: I can't imagine why you'd do that when a regex solution is so simple and avoids the string-to-array-to-string dance, which creates an unnecessary array. Moreover, in view of the OP's code attempt, it appears he/she is looking for a solution that employs a regex.